# Node-webkit secure data storage

Tags: node.js, local-storage, node-webkit

I'd like to develop an app using node-webkit which allows to connect to some remote database servers specified by user. For convinience I would like to save the required passwords.

What is the best way to securely store data in node-webkit?
Is `localstorage` safe enough?

Answer (score 0):

No, `localStorage` has no security belt.

The question is all about security when it comes to store password. Get a reference book in that domain for an extensive list of good practices. However there is a couple of things to keep in mind:

- All your code is plain Javascript and easily accessible. Even "obfuscation" is easily convertible into plain, readable Javascript.
- `NW` has few tools to store data locally. None of them is a secure storage.

You may save the password in a different remote database for convenience, which means not locally, using a secure transport.

Hope this helps,

R.

Comment: Doesn't the V8 snapshot allow you to hide the code?

Comment: I have no information about that. Nevertheless NW must be unpacked when launch. And the files are placed into a tmp folder, which is easily accessible.

Comment: Actually snapshot is a binary heap image, which is loaded into memory when the app starts. I don't think it's that easy to recover data from it. You can check it here https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit/wiki/Protect-JavaScript-source-code-with-v8-snapshot

Comment: Interesting. However compiled code can be decompiled too. Of course "almost" nobody will.

Comment: You can say that about all the compiled code, so it won't get safer then this ;) Thanks for help anyway.